# nextjs13 and styledcomponent errors

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

Hi we are using styled components and after updating to next.js 13 and react 18, and using the next config setting for styled-components we are getting some weird behaviours.

1. When extending styles like

```
const CardWrapper = styled.div`
  color: red
`
const Card = styled(CardWrapper)`
  color: green
`
```

We sometimes get the wrong style if there is a mismatch between styles, but only when we build and start the project.

3. When we run dev we get the minified classNames but the documentation says we should get the full class names
4. We sometimes run into error like this
   next-dev.js?3515:20 Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "sc-fSRBKe btBFdf" Client: "sc-bCfvAP haamXM"

Your next config:

```
next config:
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    domains: ['images.ctfassets.net'],
  },
  compiler: {
    // ssr and displayName are configured by default
    styledComponents: true,
  },

  output: 'standalone',

  async redirects() {
    ...
  }
}
module.exports = nextConfig
```

I should add we also still have the .babelrc.js do to internal packages.

Answer (score 0):

Next JS runs on SSR and it is necessary to make some configurations to run styled components on SSR. A few weeks ago I had some problems running it, but I managed to get it working with the tutorial below.

[server-side-rendering-styled-components-with-nextjs](https://medium.com/swlh/server-side-rendering-styled-components-with-nextjs-1db1353e915e)

If you want, I have a project I was developing at this link with some settings that might help.

[pokedex-for-all](https://github.com/iguana-3d/pokedex-for-all)

Comment: thank you for your input but I already had next js working with styled-components, my issues only started when I updated to next.js 13 and React 18. I don't want to use the babel config because I want to use SWR.